# repeat the same field with differents types form symfony3

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a small "big" question. 
Is it possible in a symfony form to repeat the same field with different types? If yes, how?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
            ->add('sprint', ChoiceType::class)
            ->add('sprint', SprintType::class)
            //Sprint is a ManyToOne entity
            ....
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. Maybe you can explain how the form data or view is supposed to look like to help us get the picture?

Comment: I have 2 entities Sprint and Livrable with ManyToOne RelationShip. When creating a Livrable, the user can either choose an existing sprint or create a sprint.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do sounds a bit like [the example from the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html). You want a collection of Sprints to attach to the LivrableType and also be able to create a new Sprint using [a prototype](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype).

Comment: Unfortunately as you can tell from the linked documentation page, it is not that easy to solve this with Symfony forms. You might want to look at a more frontend-centric solution using JavaScript.

Comment: Not possible as you suggested, but definitely doable with some changes made. The general idea would be to have form named `sprint` with unique subfields ( `sprint_choice`, `sprint_sprint`, etc) and then have a `DataTransformer` on top of form (not fields) which does two way transformation - thus deciding which field to pick data from and to which field to set. I am going to try to produce an example and post it later...